# Iterative Optimization of Likelihood Function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, optimization, algorithms, multivariate-normal-distribution

If we have 3 input vectors $\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3}$ let $\mathbf{y}=[\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3}]$. Based on this, I want to model $\mathbf{y}$ as belonging to a multivariate gaussian distribution

Given that $\boldsymbol{y}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}_{2}$ are independent I can write the likelihood as 
$$log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3})=log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{3}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2})+log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{1})+log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{2})$$
This factorized likelihood cannot be opitmized through opimizing each part alone as they share common hyperparameters. Thus I want to use an $\textbf{iterative algorithm}$ if possible. For instance i want to

Step 1: Optimize $log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{1})+log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{2})$ to get $\hat{\theta}_{12}$

Step 2: Plug $\hat{\theta}_{12}$ into $ log\ f(\boldsymbol{y}_{3}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2})$ to get $\hat{\theta}_{3}$

Then iterate between these two steps

Any advice on how to do this and what is a good algorithm to use? Also is this considered multiobjective optimization ?

Comment: If y is multivariate gaussian, then the parameters are the component means of y and the variance-covariance matrix of y -- no iteration necessary.

Comment: @Sycorax The covaraince matrix here contains some shared parameters which are induced to learn from dependencies